# How to extract app version from pubspec.yaml in a flutter app to use it in github actions running on windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, cmd, github-actions

I want to extract the version of my `pubspec.yaml` file of my flutter app using github actions and later reuse this version and attach it to a filename.

Here's my `main.yaml` step:

```
build_on_push:
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Get version from pubspec.yaml
        # this step echos "D:\a\my_app\my_app>set APP_VERSION=1.0.0+1" 
        run: |
          type pubspec.yaml | findstr /r "version:[^^]*" | for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /r /c:"version:[^^]*" pubspec.yaml') do set APP_VERSION=%%a
          echo APP_VERSION=!APP_VERSION!>>$GITHUB_ENV
        shell: cmd
      # doesnt work
      - name: Display the version retrieved from pubspec
        run: echo ${{ env.APP_VERSION }}
        shell: cmd
      # doesnt work
      - name: Display the version retrieved from pubspec 3
        run: echo %APP_VERSION%
        shell: cmd
```

I want to be able to use the `APP_VERSION` later but it seems I'm doing something wrong because it's never setting the variable correctly and I can't echo it and therefore I can't reference it anywhere.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables in `cmd` should be surrounded by `%` e.g. `%VAR%`.

To set a variable `VERSION` to `GITHUB_ENV`, you can use:

```
echo VERSION=%VERSION% >> %GITHUB_ENV%
```

and, in the subsequent steps, it can be accessed like this:

```
echo VERSION=%VERSION%
```

or, with `env` context:

```
echo VERSION=${{ env.VERSION }}
```

---

For processing YAML, you can use [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) command line utility. Contrary to Linux and Mac runners, `yq` is not [preinstalled](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) on the Windows runners so you'll have to install it first with `choco install yq`.

With `yq`, this would extract the `version` from the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
yq -r .version pubspec.yaml
```

The following will extract and set it to env var using an intermediate file:

```
yq -r .version pubspec.yaml > version.file
set /p VERSION=<version.file
echo VERSION=%VERSION% >> %GITHUB_ENV%
```

As you have moved on to **Powershell**, you can still install and use `yq`:

```
$VERSION=(yq -r .version pubspec.yaml)
echo VERSION=$VERSION | Out-File -FilePath $ENV:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

---

If you consider using Linux runners in the future, you might as well use [`yq` GitHub Action](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/github-action):

```yaml
name: CI

on: push

jobs:
  build_on_push:
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Get version
      id: yq
      uses: mikefarah/yq@master
      with:
        cmd: yq -r '.version' 'pubspec.yaml'

    - name: Print version
      run: echo ${{ steps.yq.outputs.result }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it. I had to switch from cmd to powershell to make it work. The `main.yaml`looks as follows:

```
build_on_push:
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get version from pubspec.yaml
        run: |
          $version = (Get-Content pubspec.yaml | Select-String 'version:[^^]*' | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString().Split(":")[1].Trim() })
          echo "APP_VERSION=$version" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
      - name: Use the value
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.APP_VERSION }}"
```